# How can I export all the data from an image collection and add the coordinates as a band

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, coordinates

I have a collection of data to which I apply several filters, when I try to export the coordinates of the remaining data after applying the filter, ALL THE COORDINATES appear, I only need the coordinates that have data in band 1

```
//Multi-coordinates of the bay of Cartagena, Colombia
var cartagena_bay = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-75.59124018269034, 10.295095693101942],
          [-75.58634790679292, 10.298895904175886],
          [-75.57888058446188, 10.301513727339154],
          [-75.57724980608958, 10.298473622420074],
          [-75.57682065841429, 10.294251169634652],
          [-75.57690648200273, 10.288930876156382],
          [-75.58033970545154, 10.28377936704133],
          [-75.57802225669393, 10.276685317971417],
          [-75.57493237817081, 10.273644992335656],
          [-75.56720762859463, 10.271618079124194],
          [-75.55690796247369, 10.275334076668155],
          [-75.54214510772397, 10.284961685255555],
          [-75.53047215283398, 10.291042128937237],
          [-75.53253208607153, 10.30117594130479],
          [-75.53218876388341, 10.307762744672722],
          [-75.52600896974832, 10.302611540178997],
          [-75.52489316623732, 10.298642510006669],
          [-75.52103079228097, 10.296784662622876],
          [-75.51828421466152, 10.296784662633867],
          [-75.51982916459535, 10.302358198238537],
          [-75.51055946515113, 10.304722698769218],
          [-75.5072979042126, 10.301513729541728],
          [-75.50420800439639, 10.302020411087451],
          [-75.50661125987962, 10.312998310751851],
          [-75.51038780190534, 10.316629378344052],
          [-75.51176109298291, 10.327860088050574],
          [-75.51004448200892, 10.333095319615822],
          [-75.51158943193838, 10.33816158968168],
          [-75.50970115987225, 10.344241005904504],
          [-75.50901451550212, 10.349307096143674],
          [-75.5112461098242, 10.353866507400072],
          [-75.51090278766972, 10.361971963735849],
          [-75.50970116003168, 10.3721034892947],
          [-75.51433600976019, 10.382403537423352],
          [-75.52120245372161, 10.38409203751985],
          [-75.5253223200989, 10.385780528512855],
          [-75.51948584272002, 10.380883879491822],
          [-75.5242923534827, 10.37885765744315],
          [-75.53476368053263, 10.386287074013987],
          [-75.53819690251532, 10.392534401298036],
          [-75.5349353416486, 10.39641781205879],
          [-75.5308154752841, 10.396080126091903],
          [-75.52652394783964, 10.401989577936082],
          [-75.53682361374071, 10.402664936714515],
          [-75.54025683570792, 10.403677972171266],
          [-75.54060015790947, 10.409924951495071],
          [-75.54454836316671, 10.413132811172074],
          [-75.55175812929912, 10.397768552301137],
          [-75.54231676888176, 10.392872091103174],
          [-75.54334673547164, 10.388313247891542],
          [-75.55553467347201, 10.393378625138304],
          [-75.55810958995734, 10.390001716107301],
          [-75.56652098377324, 10.395573596461759],
          [-75.57544736095615, 10.382910088411995],
          [-75.5690959003174, 10.37784454151334],
          [-75.56068450648364, 10.37075263807875],
          [-75.5515864682296, 10.367544343260601],
          [-75.54197344666932, 10.366362331624279],
          [-75.53845439412738, 10.361043224074972],
          [-75.53407703608178, 10.35589289105067],
          [-75.53665195257167, 10.353022176895688],
          [-75.54231676886178, 10.354541970008775],
          [-75.53562198596771, 10.349307096048141],
          [-75.5419689662549, 10.341237264914186],
          [-75.54529492660438, 10.340603983045764],
          [-75.54814876585738, 10.335031133581703],
          [-75.55085242818436, 10.33583329351309],
          [-75.55115283510875, 10.336804326477267],
          [-75.55235446223882, 10.337933679354288],
          [-75.5556589388617, 10.335769970669048],
          [-75.55831968604195, 10.335242228510642],
          [-75.55933890100452, 10.33606549273609],
          [-75.5616455985749, 10.337775355595223],
          [-75.56342660376278, 10.338408635254371],
          [-75.56370017707366, 10.34249851711689],
          [-75.56488839202446, 10.343361355916477],
          [-75.56659159200474, 10.34287321473528],
          [-75.56842622144455, 10.34024513861361],
          [-75.5697780644573, 10.340561773618454],
          [-75.57299671312036, 10.338281982468182],
          [-75.57475623638292, 10.33515779061402],
          [-75.57758865266723, 10.334524501742214],
          [-75.57522831132734, 10.329964805697015],
          [-75.57497081338829, 10.328613772834037],
          [-75.57291087958761, 10.327938262000083],
          [-75.57557162666745, 10.32287182714731],
          [-75.57823238341034, 10.320591911177907],
          [-75.58012064586235, 10.317129769005849],
          [-75.59316688950858, 10.317636425494348]]]);

//Function to apply scale bands in MODIS-Terra
function scale_bands (image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('sur_refl_b.*').multiply(0.0001)
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])}

//Remove pixels with negative values
function remove_pixels_negative (image){
  var image_without_pixels_negative = image
  image_without_pixels_negative = image_without_pixels_negative.updateMask(image_without_pixels_negative.select('sur_refl_b03').gte(0)) //Blue band
  image_without_pixels_negative = image_without_pixels_negative.updateMask(image_without_pixels_negative.select('sur_refl_b04').gte(0)) //Green band
  image_without_pixels_negative = image_without_pixels_negative.updateMask(image_without_pixels_negative.select('sur_refl_b01').gte(0)) //Red band
  image_without_pixels_negative = image_without_pixels_negative.updateMask(image_without_pixels_negative.select('sur_refl_b05').gte(0)) //Near InfraRed band
  
  return image.addBands(image_without_pixels_negative, null, true).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

//Function Cloud Mask
var cloud_mask = function(image) {
 var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks') //Repository from the code to cloud mask
 var mask = cld.modisSR(['cirrus','cloud','cloud2','shadow'])(image) //apply cloud mask
 return mask.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

//Function Land Mask
function mask_water(image){
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b01'])
  return image.updateMask(ndwi.gt(0)).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

//Function cloud filter
function filter_clouds_modis (image) {
  var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks') //Repository from the code to cloud mask
  var mask = cld.modisSR(['cirrus','cloud','cloud2','shadow'])(image) //apply cloud mask
  
  var image_without_cloud_mask = image.select('sur_refl_b01') //image without cloud mask
  var image_with_cloud_mask = mask.select('sur_refl_b01') //image with cloud mask
  
  //You can use any band. In this example, I am using sur_refl_b01. 
  //I just need to count the pixels without any mask applied
  
  //Counting pixels number in cartagena bay in image without cloud mask
  var count_image_without_cloud_mask = image_without_cloud_mask.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.count(),cartagena_bay,500,null,null,false,1e13).get('sur_refl_b01')
  count_image_without_cloud_mask = ee.Number(count_image_without_cloud_mask).divide(1e6)
  
  //Counting pixels number in cartagena bay in image with cloud mask
  var count_image_with_cloud_mask = image_with_cloud_mask.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.count(),cartagena_bay,500,null,null,false,1e13).get('sur_refl_b01')
  count_image_with_cloud_mask = ee.Number(count_image_with_cloud_mask).divide(1e6)
  
  //Calculating the ratio between image with cloud masking and without cloud masking for get to cloud filter percentage
  var cloud_filter_percentage = (ee.Number(1).subtract(count_image_with_cloud_mask.divide(count_image_without_cloud_mask))).multiply(100)
  
  //Add proprietes for the cloud filter percentage number
  return image.set('CLOUD_COVER_BAY', cloud_filter_percentage)
}

//Function to Deglint
function deglint (image) {
  
  var time_start = image.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']) //For copy proprietes time_sytem
  
  //Apply linear regression between visible bands and NIR with shortwave infrared
    var linearFitBlue = image.select(['sur_refl_b05', 'sur_refl_b03']).reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), geometry: cartagena_bay, scale: 500});
    var linearFitGreen = image.select(['sur_refl_b05', 'sur_refl_b04']).reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), geometry: cartagena_bay, scale: 500});
    var linearFitRed = image.select(['sur_refl_b05', 'sur_refl_b01']).reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), geometry: cartagena_bay, scale: 500});
  var linearFitNir = image.select(['sur_refl_b05', 'sur_refl_b02']).reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), geometry: cartagena_bay, scale: 500});
  
  //Obtaning slope from linear regression
    var slopeImage = ee.Dictionary({'sur_refl_b03': linearFitBlue.get('scale'),
    'sur_refl_b04': linearFitGreen.get('scale'),
    'sur_refl_b01': linearFitRed.get('scale'),
    'sur_refl_b02': linearFitNir.get('scale')}).toImage().toFloat()

  //Obtaning minimum SWIR values
    var minSWIR = image.select('sur_refl_b05').reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), cartagena_bay).toImage()

  //Apply method of Hedley et al., (2005)
    var image_deglint = image.select(['sur_refl_b03', 'sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b01', 'sur_refl_b02']).subtract(slopeImage.multiply((image.select('sur_refl_b05').subtract(minSWIR))))
  
  //When subtracting the values by the minimum of the swir, 
  //there is a risk that some values will become negative
  //Therefore, you must ensure that negative values are removed again
  image_deglint = image_deglint.updateMask(image_deglint.select('sur_refl_b03').gte(0)) //Blue band
  image_deglint = image_deglint.updateMask(image_deglint.select('sur_refl_b04').gte(0)) //Green band
  image_deglint = image_deglint.updateMask(image_deglint.select('sur_refl_b01').gte(0)) //Red band
  image_deglint = image_deglint.updateMask(image_deglint.select('sur_refl_b02').gte(0)) //Near InfraRed
  
  return image.addBands(image_deglint, null, true).copyProperties(time_start, ['system:time_start'])
}

//I drew a square around the bay so as not to show the entire modis scene, just the bay region.
function clip (image){return image.clipToCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(geometry))}

//Image Collection MODIS-Terra 500m
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD09GA')
                .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01') //Range data 
                .map(clip) // Clip to cartagena bay
                .map(filter_clouds_modis) //Apply filter cloud
                .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER_BAY', 'less_than', 20) //Filtering cloud cover less than 20%
                .map(scale_bands) //Apply scale band of MODIS-Terra
                .map(cloud_mask) //Apply cloud mask
                .map(mask_water) //Apply land mask
                .map(deglint) //Apply glint correction

//Centering in cartagena bay
Map.setCenter(-75.54307476890797, 10.324208272791243)

print('All scenes from image collection filtered by cloud filter')
print(dataset)
```